# GExperts grep expression for source lines with string literals (for translation)

Tags: delphi, internationalization, grep, gexperts

How can I find all lines in Delphi source code using GExperts grep search which contain a string literal instead of a resource string, except those lines which are marked as `'do not translate'`?

Example:

this line should match

```
  ShowMessage('Fatal error! Save all data and restart the application');
```

this line should not match

```
  FieldByName('End Date').Clear; // do not translate
```

(Asking specifically about GExpert as it has a limited grep implementation afaik)

Comment: Personally I'd use command-line grep

Comment: +1 for the Question. i would ask in the GExpertsDiscuss http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/GExpertsDiscuss/

Comment: good idea - maybe this can be implemented as a new expert...

Comment: the problem is that you want to negate only a *part* of your expression, and that is something Regular Expressions do not support at all, nor Grep -v does.

Answer (score 2):

[Regular Expressions cannot be negated in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word).

Since you want to negate a portion of the search, this comes as close as I could get it within the RegEx boundaries that GExpers Grep Search understands:

```
\'.*\'.*[^n][^o][^t][^ ][^t][^r][^a][^n][^s][^l][^a][^t][^e]$
```

*Edit:* Forgot the end-of-line $ marker, as GExperts Grep Search cannot do without.

[blokhead](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=137386) explains why you [cannot negate in general](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=588315#588368).

This Visual Studio Quick Search [uses the tilde for negation](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showpost.php?s=c301d10e66740023dc93accfad4e5cf2&p=30714&postcount=5), but the GExperts Grep Search cannot.

The grep command-line search has the `-v` (re*v*erse) option to negate a complete search (but not a partial search).

A perfect [manual](http://osrd.org/projects/grep/negation-in-regular-expressions) negation [gets complicated very rapidly](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/763719-regular-expression-negate-word-not-character).

--jeroen

Comment: when I do this I just do a positve search with grep and then pipe it into a negative one using -v

Comment: How do you pipe a GExperts Grep Search?

Comment: @David: how do you make that output clickable, so you can jump to source lines in the editor? I think that is what `mjn` is after. I remember (but forgot which IDE that is), you can have tools output in the output window, to make it clickable. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: @Jeroen You can't do that with grep. I use grep for things like this because I actually get the results I want! It would be nice if I could jump straight to the match, but first priority is usually getting the right match.

Comment: The expression gives false positives, for example with:  `if Pos('.', PropName) > 0 then // do not translate`

Comment: @mjn: sorry, I forgot to put in the $, it works here, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @David: the problem is that @mjn wants to negate only a *part* of the  expression, and that is something Regular Expressions do not support at all, nor `grep -v` does.